# UIScrollView is Zooming but every thing on scrollview is also zooming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollview, zooming

I am using a `scrollview` and I am zooming my `scrollview`.

I want that if i zoom my `scrollview` only background `imageview` which in the `Scrollview` can zoom and a small image on `scrollview` should not zoom.

Consider a map , if i am zooming map the map zooms but a placemark on that map would remain as it is in terms of size and place..

Same thing i want with my `scrollview`.
Any help please?

Comment: do you need to scroll that small image as well?

Comment: i want like map, in map when you zoom the map is zooming but placemark is not zooming.

Comment: it means that image can be fixed on screen.

Comment: just consider a map and placemark on it i want same,if map zooms the place mark will on New York  and zoom out it would on same position New York..

Comment: Now paste the code yo have used to zoom, have you not given image view as a view  for zooming?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Seems like an easy problem to fix. But I have nto found a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the image view on top of the zooming scroll-view. The order in which the sub-views are added will matter here. So, first add the scroll view that zooms and then the image view